# Wscript and Tor Browser

Tags: wsh, tor

so I'm new to all of this and I need to know if wscripts would work with tor browser, and what would that code look like. i need the bot to go to a website and click a button and then go to another different website, and all on tor browser. I was wonder if that's possible and what I would have to write for it to work.

Comment: If you just have to click a button... Why don't you use `Python`? Why `wsh`?

Answer (score 1):

No. Tor Browser uses Firefox which does not support Microsoft VBScript, and the default security settings may not permit it even if it did.

The only way it may work is if a user configures an old version of Internet Explorer to use Tor's SOCKS proxy. Edge doesn't support VBScript at all.

This article also points out that Microsoft killed VBScript by default in IE in August 2019. [What is VBScript, and Why Did Microsoft Just Kill It?](https://www.howtogeek.com/437372/what-is-vbscript-and-why-did-microsoft-just-kill-it/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim s
Set s = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
s.Run "torbrowsername"
WScript.Sleep (16000)
s.SendKeys "^{T}"
WScript.Sleep (1000)
s.SendKeys "website1.example"
s.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep (4000)
s.SendKeys "{TAB}"
s.SendKeys "{SPACE}"
WScript.Sleep (4000)
s.SendKeys "^{T}"
s.SendKeys "website2.example"
s.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```